# symfony2.6 custom command with doctrine and swift

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, swiftmailer

Trying to build a custom command. Need get some records from DB by Doctrine and send email by SwiftMailer. Use symfony 2.6.1. I've code:

```
namespace MyBundle\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;


class Raport extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('raport:count-day')
            ->setDescription('test');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $em->getRepository('My:Application')->findAll();
        // $output->writeln($text);
    }
}
```

When I run command in console raport:count-day always receive the same error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Console\Application::getKernel() in /var/www/auto/pzu-voucher/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.php on line 42 ($this->container = $application->getKernel()->getContainer();)
```

anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: how are you executing this command?

Answer (score 1):

I used custom application to run commands, and here I had done something wrong. My commands works correctly when I run it via the app/console

sorry

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should follow [Command documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) :

> To make the console commands available automatically with Symfony,
>   create a **Command directory inside your bundle** and create a PHP file
>   **suffixed with Command.php** for each command that you want to provide.

Your class should also be renamed to `ReportCommand`.

Comment: This isn't related to the problem @Piotr is getting

Comment: rename class, namespacess and move file too write directory. Still have errors :(

Comment: @Piotr, the suggestion of @AlterPHP is good because of some trick on the `Bundle` class. Take a look at [this article](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/10/symfony2-console-commands-as-services-why/)